# Error in installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I am struggling to install Ubuntu 18.04 on first Huawei Y11C and then on Lenovo T460 Thinkpad. Both installation is giving error as shown in image.

[image]

Need help I also tried different usb iso tools to create a bootable device but still it is showing this error.

Comment: Your ISO image is likely corrupt. Try downloading it again and check it before burning.

Comment: How to check it that its not getting corrupted

Comment: Checksum is what you're looking for. Try googling it because comments are limited.

Comment: Ok trying again

Comment: It has a squashfs read error so it's either a bad download (md5sum check etc - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) or it was a bad write to your install-media (cd/thumb-drive etc) in which case the check-disc-for-defects option on the installer is what you want (https://manual.lubuntu.me/1/1.3/installation.html shows the menu for lubuntu, or look again at your attached screen at the top!)